# How can I stub FileSystems.getDefault() method using mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, filesystemwatcher, stubbing

Here is the problem statement. I want to confirm (in my Test method) that `fileSystem.newWatchService()` is invoked within my target method. I am getting the default `FileSystem` instance (using `FileSystems.getDefault()`) in my target method. Anyone know how I can stub `FileSystems.getDefault()` so that I can return my Mock FileSystem instance?

Here is my test method.

```
@Test
public final void FMS_Creates_A_New_FolderWatcher_From_FileSystem()
{
    try {

        // Arrange
        FileSystem mockFileSystem = mock(FileSystem.class);

        // Your solution will go here!!!
        when(FileSystems.getDefault()).thenReturn(mockFileSystem); // this doesn't work!!
        // Act
        FMS _target = new FMS();
        _target.run();

        // Assert
        verify(mockFileSystem, times(1)).newWatchService();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // There handled!!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## Addendum: While I was initially facing problem stubbing the FileSystems.getFileSystem() method, the actual issue was more design oriented. By calling default FileSystem, I was expanding my methods scope of behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: Why, why, _why_ would you do this instead of making the `FMS` constructor accept a `FileSystem` argument?  Part of the _point_ of the `FileSystem` API is that you can inject alternate filesystems through the constructor instead of trying to hack around the default behavior.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I knew I was gonna be reprimanded for shortcuts. Yes, you are right, I should inject the FileSystem. argh!!!

Comment: Mocking static things is essentially always an indication that it shouldn't be static; that you should be injecting it instead.

Comment: @durron597, Thanks. Yes, this would be a suitable solution to stub the static method. But I am leaning towards injecting FS.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, do you mind re-posting your original comment as an answer instead of comment so that I may tag it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mocking a static method -- which is usually a symptom of badly designed code -- pass in the `FileSystem` through the `FMS` constructor instead.  This is part of the point of dependency injection.